# Line chart thickness to be Independent of the fill styling

Tags: reactjs, charts, chart.js, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

I am using `react-chartjs-2`, Version: `^5.2.0`

As you can see from the images, I am trying to apply a gradient fill on a line chart.

But the gradient styling is also applied on the line itself.

Is there a way to separate out the styling of the line and the gradient fill effect ?

What I have:

[image]

What I am trying to achieve:

Increase the thickness of the line while maintaining the gradient fill in the background.

[image]

Relevant code:

```
function getGradient(ctx, chartArea) {
  let gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(
    0,
    chartArea.bottom,
    0,
    chartArea.top,
  );
  gradient.addColorStop(0.9, "#5A9EF566");
  gradient.addColorStop(0.4, "#5A9EF52F");
  gradient.addColorStop(0, "#5A9EF500");
  return gradient;
}

const apiRespnose = [
    {
      timestamp: "08:24",
      orderCount: "95",
    },
    {
      timestamp: "08:25",
      orderCount: "107",
    },
    {
      timestamp: "08:26",
      orderCount: "105",
    }];

const data = {
  labels: apiRespnose.map((e) => e.timestamp),
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "No of orders",
      data: apiRespnose.map((e) => Number(e.orderCount)),
      borderColor: "#5A9EF566",
      pointStyle: "circle",
      fill: true,
      backgroundColor: function (context) {
        const chart = context.chart;
        const { ctx, chartArea } = chart;
        if (!chartArea) return;
        return getGradient(ctx, chartArea);
      },
      borderWidth: 2,
    },
  ],
}

<LineChart data={data} />
```

Comment: I don't think that the gradient is applied to the line color; there might be a slight "contamination" from the fill because the line color is transparent. If you set the `borderColor` to a non-transparent value (at least for a test) I think there will be no gradient effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `borderColor` to a static color that will make it so that your line is one single color but the fill is still a gradient

Comment: As you can see in the code that I have shared in the qn, I have set a borderColor.
If, I misunderstood, can you please clarify more ?